# Time complexity of double loop, if inner loop starts on the outer loop's iteration

Tags: big-o

what is the time complexity in Big O notation of this loop?

Below example is written in python but its the idea that the inner loop starts from i not 0. Does that make it not O(n^2)?

```
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i, n):
```

Comment: Yes, it's still in O(n^2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O Nested for Loop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223176/big-o-nested-for-loop-issue)